# Trouble with filling up faces, irregular shape

Tags: faces

I have problem with filling up the face, of the vertices, the curved part has sorta wing look alike joined to the vertices, can anyone help with this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by irregular vertex order.
*Fill* operation works well in such cases.

1. Select all vertices, *Select > All* (<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Go *Face > Fill*, (<kbd>Alt + F</kbd>)
3. Join triangles into one shape through *Vertex > New face*, (<kbd>F</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: There's one I didn't know about!

Answer (score 0):

don't try to fill them at once, first the rect then the loop , dissolve the faces together