# How to use Fill command for faces?

Tags: faces

I tried asking this question and then found a similar one with a supposed solution:
[Trouble with filling up faces, irregular shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170705/trouble-with-filling-up-faces-irregular-shape)

The steps shown here return 'No faces filled' regardless of combination of vertices selected, even with a joined shape. Is there a bug in 2.82 with regard to Face-Fill command?

[image]

This is a polygon drawn by extruding a single vertex. The Face-Fill command works on the areas shown with faces (but the normal F command also would).
What would be the procedure to leave this area as a whole and create faces (the 2.82 manual shows this like one easy step).

[image]

One of the shapes I'd like to fill with Face-Fill, a letter created in Inkscape, imported as an SVG and converted to a mesh. 'F' creates faces in certain places within a letter, but it's not consistent and Face-Fill looks like it's what I need.

Comment: Wellcom J. M. Pleas add further information and screnshots of what you are trying to fill for clarification.

Comment: Fill command works as it's supposed to in 2.82. Maybe try enabling F2 add-on in the preferences and use F to fill. The functionality is much more advanced with the add-on enabled.

Comment: Hi there, I tried enabling the F2 add-on in Preferences, then I attempted to follow the instructions in the 2.82 manual (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/mesh/f2.html). Do I have to select the object first in Object mode and then switch to Edit mode, or should I hit F2 in Edit mode? I'm not getting the error message 'No faces filled' any more, but it's not doing what I've seen in a tutorial on the F2 add-on (differing functionality depending on cursor). How do I go about adding screenshots here?

Comment: Hi Martynas and J. Doe, I've updated my post with a couple of screenshots. It seems to me that Face-Fill isn't really working, because it just does what the 'F' command normally does. If Face-Fill can detect holes then I imagine it can be made to fill in a letter and leave the central part of an 'A' or a 'B' blank, no? Thanks for your help.